# onChange function is not called in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, onchange

im trying o set a onChange Function when there is a change on the dropdown.
onChange it should be forwarded to another Side (using Navbar in React)

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../index.css'; 
import { Navbar } from "../components";
import { BodyMain } from '../components';

function handleChange() {
  <Link to="/check1"> </Link>
}

const options = [
  { value: 'Claire', label: 'Claire', },
  { value: 'Coco', label: 'Coco' },
  { value: 'Emma', label: 'Emma' },
  { value: 'Leni', label: 'Leni' },


const hotel = () => {
  return(

<Select onChange={handleChange} options={options} /> 
 
     )
}

export default hotel;
```

How can i bring that handleChange to life?

Thank you

As seen i tried to set the onChange right after the select, also on different positions such as in the const [option]

Ive seen other documentations where they had a smaller  im using the bigger one with  it does make a colour change but i dont know where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

Hm, are you trying to navigate somewhere in case of change of the dropdown? All you're doing here is creating a link element when someone changes the select. You should use [redirect feature](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.3/fetch/redirect) of React router. So when someone changes the select, it redirects them to another site.

In your specific example, it would be like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import '../index.css'; 
import { Navbar } from "../components";
import { BodyMain } from '../components';


const options = [
  { value: 'Claire', label: 'Claire', },
  { value: 'Coco', label: 'Coco' },
  { value: 'Emma', label: 'Emma' },
  { value: 'Leni', label: 'Leni' },

 
const Hotel = () => { //since this is a component, it should have Uppercase name (Hotel instead of hotel)
      const navigate = useNavigate(); //There's no reason for handleChange to be outside of the component
      const handleChange = () => { 
            navigate("/check1") 
      }

      return(
      <Select onChange={handleChange} options={options} /> 
      )
}

export default Hotel;
```

Comment: can you show me how to use it in my scenario? Where to put the const or redirect class ?

Comment: @NoobCoder Just replace this: 
"function handleChange() {
  <Link to="/check1"> </Link>
}" with this:
const handleChange = () => {
navigate("/check1")
}. Actually, I'll edit my reply for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to another route when you make a change, you'll have to use useNavigate from react-router-dom.

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'.

const navigate = useNavigate()

function handleChange = () => {
   navigate("/check1")
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it sows:  "(" was expected   right behind the handleChange "="

Comment: im sorry its 1- function handleChange() { navigate("/check1")}, or 2- const handleChange = () =>{ navigate("/check1")} . One is arrow function and the other is a normal function

Comment: @Martin small mistake in your code your using arrow function and normal function syntax toghater.